# The grumphp precommit does not detect any errors

Tags: php, symfony, phpcs, php-cs-fixer

I cannot get `grumphp` to work in a subdirectory.

My directory structure is below :

```
/api/grumphp.yml

/api/composer.json

/api/src/
```

grumphp.yml contents:

```
parameters:
    git_dir: ../.
    bin_dir: vendor/bin
    ascii:
        failed: ~
        succeeded: ~
    tasks:
        phplint: ~
        phpcsfixer2: ~
        xmllint:
            ignore_patterns: []
            load_from_net: true
            x_include: false
            dtd_validation: true
            scheme_validation: true
            triggered_by: [xml]
```

My composer.json file contains:

```
  "extra": {
    "grumphp": {
      "config-default-path": "./grumphp.yml"
    }
```

Output

```
GrumPHP detected a pre-commit command.
GrumPHP is sniffing your code!
Running task 1/3: PhpCsFixerV2... ✔
Running task 2/3: PhpLint... ✔
Running task 3/3: XmlLint... ✔

GrumPHP detected a commit-msg command.
GrumPHP is sniffing your code!
```

Running the command `vendor/bin/grumphp run` does give me the expected PHPCS errors

Comment: Did you try the `whitelist_patterns ` part of this doc https://github.com/phpro/grumphp/blob/master/doc/tasks/phpcs.md ?

Comment: @Mcsky I think it is not that. When running the command vendor/bin/grumphp run it does give the expected CS errors

Comment: Ha I didn't see this part of the question. So which command don't work ?  Just `grumphp` ?

Comment: @Mcsky the precommit. The tasks are run. But it looks like they don't get the changed files as input.

Comment: @HenneVanOch Did you manage to resolve the issue? If yes, can you add an answer.